# How To Run A Github Repository?

Tags: sql, github

I'm a coding newbie, so this may be sort of a dumb question. I was working on an SQL project to learn the language and I wanted to know if there was a way to download and execute a Github repository, I haven't used Github before. Thanks!

Comment: By "run a github repository," do you mean "act as a manager of" or "download the software and execute it?"

Comment: I meant to download the software and execute it.

Comment: @KatePearce if any of these answers have answered your question you should accept it so the poster can receive credit.  If not you should close the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a newbie, I think you should learn how to use git.
You can refer the link below: https://education.github.com/git-cheat-sheet-education.pdf

Basic steps:

1. Clone or download source code from Github.
   You can download it directly, or use a tool like Git-bash, tortoise git...
2. Run this source code, depending on the language of the source code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run any code in a Github repository, you will need to either download it or clone it to your machine.  Click the green "clone or download repository" button on the top right of the repository. In order to clone, you will need to have git installed on your computer.  Then, follow [these instructions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/clone-a-repository-223217891.html). You could also just click download.  Once you have it on your machine, how you run the code will depend on what type of code your project is written in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you found a repository relating to SQL on Github that you want to run, the best thing to do is to scroll down and read about that repository I'm sure most of the time there are instructions there on how to install or run the repo and from there if you don't understand something try Googling that keyword I'm sure Google has an answer for that and also best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you use codesandbox you can import and export from it to github. So, when you go to codesandbox, the very left bar, click on the rocket (deployments) and deploy to Github (pages). But I'm sure there must be a way to also do it from github via github actions, but I couldn't figure out either

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly run the code because it only can run based on specific environments like using python. Instead of using git to clone the code, you could download the code zip file through the code button on the github project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `git clone` command to download a GitHub repository to your local machine.

1. Install `git` if you don't have it on your device.
2. Open your terminal or command prompt.
3. Navigate to the Directory: Use the `cd` command to navigate to the directory where you want to download the repository.
4. Clone the Repository: Use the `git clone` command followed by the URL of the GitHub repository.
5. Excute the SQL project.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1:

Open GitHub and navigate to the main page of the repository.

Step 2:

Under the repository name, click on Clone or download.

Step 3:

Select the Clone with HTTPs section and copy the clone URL for the repository. For the empty repository, you can copy the repository page URL from your browser.

Now just go to your Ide(editor) and open terminal just enter the below command, click to Enter.

command : **git clone** [url]

$example -> "git clone [https://github.com/ImDwivedi1/Git-Example.git"](https://github.com/ImDwivedi1/Git-Example.git%22)

Now you can see folder has been created in your directory.